# Hibernate provides next generated id 32768 and so on 65536, 98304

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, persistence, auto-increment

**EMPLOYEE.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="EMPLOYEE")
public class Employee implements Serializable {

@Id
@GeneratedValue( strategy = GenerationType.TABLE)
```

**EMPLOYEE (TABLE)**

```
1   3/13/2013   911 Jack    Bauer

32768   3/13/2013   911 Jack    Bauer

65536   3/13/2013   911 Jack    Bauer

98304   3/13/2013   911 Jack    Bauer
```

**HIBERNATE_SEQUENCES(TABLE) HOLDING CORRECT NUMBER**

```
EMPLOYEE    4
```

Comment: For some reason the values are shifted fifteen bits to the left.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
@TableGenerator(name="tabgen",table="employee-id",pkColumnName="name",valueColumnName="value",allocationSize=1)
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.TABLE, generator="tabgen")
```

however, its always better to use increment or sequence instead of table generation if you need the ids to be in sequence. the random ids which u see with default table strategy is because of the need to support multiple threads all simulteneously trying to insert.

Comment: seperate table feature is provided by javax.persistence , I think this is also reliable and have a better option. I am using because our project must support different databases

Comment: with allocation size 1, be aware that each insert will now also fetch the value of id - one extra query per insert.

Comment: dear, this table also manage by hibernate. if hibernate fetch /manage before insert . I  think it is ok.