# increment or sequence instead of table generation JPA

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I am developing an application that support multiple databases and hibernate fulfilling that requirement.

Now the issue is in primary auto generate key. some databases support auto increment and some required sequence for increment the identity. to solve this issue the use the following strategy

```
strategy = GenerationType.TABLE (javax.persistence)
```

This is fulfilling my requirement.

in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15393534/hibernate-provides-next-generated-id-32768-and-so-on-65536-98304), a user comment that

**its always better to use increment or sequence instead of table generation if you need the ids to be in sequence**

If I use the auto increment or sequence, it means it required some changes @ annotation level, when I move one database to another (extra burden)

update me , it is really better to use increment or sequence instead of table generation  or it is just a statement?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Answer (score 0):

Auto increment drawbacks: You don't know the id until the transaction has committed (which can be a problem in JPA, since some EntityManager operations rely on Id's). Not all databases support auto increment fields.

Sequence drawbacks: Not all databases have sequences.

Table drawbacks: Id's are not necessarily consecutive.

Since it is very unlikely that you run out of Id's, using Table generation remains a good option. You can even tweak the id allocation size in order to use more consecutive id's (default size is 50):

```
@TableGenerator(name="myGenerator", allocationSize=1)
```

However, this will result in at least two queries to the id allocation table for each insert: one to step the value of the latest id, and one to retrieve it.

Comment: If you are using a sequence (as opposed to an auto_increment) you *can* know the ID before the transaction is committed - even *before* you do the insert.

Comment: Yep, as well as with table generation.

Comment: But table generation (if I understand that concept correctly) is much slower and far less scalable. And today all modern DBMS support sequences anyway

Comment: Mysql doesn't have sequences